# Make margin effect on elements padding?

Tags: css

I have an element with a bottom margin and below it an element with padding. The margin is effective to the element's text, not to its padding. How can I make it effective to the element including its padding?

```
p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
a {
  padding: 40px;
  background: green;
}
<p class="first">First</p>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGmevv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline elements are not affected by vertical margings. Make your anchor tag display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

U need to read about block & inline html elements;

**a**`(<a/>`) - is a inline elements which one cannot has a vertical padding, turn it into block

```
display: block
```

or into inline-block:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `display: inline-block` to your `a` tag :

```
a {
  padding: 40px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

without this the `a` tag will "ignore" the padding and not let it effect the elements height or width.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `display:inline-block` to the anchor to get the desired result.

your final css should be

```
p {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
a {
 padding: 40px;
 background: green;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```css
p {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
}

a {
    background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="first">First</p>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```